# Перебор всех заданных символов в python

Tags: python, строки, комбинаторика, перебор

Мне нужно написать программу, которая выдавала бы все комбинации из заданных символов одной строкой. Я видел подобные решения, однако в них используется либо несколько строк, либо itertools, который я не люблю из-за скорости. В общем, нужно эффективное решение. Желательно, чтобы максимальную длину строки можно было задавать.
**Входные данные:** "abcd", 3 *(макс. количество символов)*
**Выходные данные:** ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', и т.д., 'aaa', 'aab' и т.д.]

Comment: Что там со скоростью itertools? Не раскрыто. А то, что любите - не нашли? Если любите скорость, пишите на c++!:)

Comment: itertools в среднем имеют наиболее высокую скорость исполнения, т.к. основываются на написанных на Си программах. Можете предоставить результаты замеров скорости Вашей программы в различных реализациях? И код самих программ, естественно.

Comment: https://overcoder.net/q/938124/python-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81 Руководсвовался данной ссылкой

Comment: Обрати внимание на combinatoric iterators  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

Специально по вашему заказу не использовал itertools, а написал высокоскоростную функцию на Numba движке (плюс Numpy), для его использования установите его один раз через `python -m pip install numpy numba`.

Также хочу заметить, что если очень важно иметь большую скорость и уметь обрабатывать большие данные, то нужно весь код со строками писать на Numpy в вашей программе. Т.к. если у вас был запрос вернуть в виде списка строк (list of str), то это очень медленная структура как для создания, так и использования. Если нужна скорость, только Numpy (или Numba) используйте всюду.

Я замерил у себя, Numba код который делает собственно комбинации, он исполняется 5% времени всего, а 95% остального времени тратится на то чтобы конвертировать Numpy в list of str структуру, очень большие потери.

Я провёл тест скорости для строки входной из 10 символов и генерации всех под-строк длиной до 6 символов (включительно). Количество сгенерированных комбинаций `1111110` (больше 1 млн), время генерации 0.55 секунд, время на одну подстроку 0.49 микро-секунды.

Для генерации списка строк моим кодом просто используйте для примера вызов `comb('abcdefghij', 1, 6)` (значит сгенерировать все комбинации длинной от 1 до 6 (включительно)), именно на таком вызове я собрал статистику времени выше.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1221735#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, numba, timeit

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def ncomb(s, k):
    a = np.zeros((len(s),), dtype = np.uint32)
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        a[i] = ord(ch)
    n = a.size
    cnt = n ** k
    c = np.empty((cnt, k), dtype = np.uint32)
    idx = np.zeros((k,), dtype = np.uint32)
    pos = 0
    while True:
        for i in range(k):
            c[pos, i] = a[idx[i]]
        pos += 1
        for i in range(k - 1, -1, -1):
            if idx[i] >= n - 1:
                idx[i] = 0
            else:
                idx[i] += 1
                break
        else:
            break
    assert pos == cnt
    return c

def comb(s, kmin, kmax):
    l = []
    for k in range(kmin, kmax + 1):
        r = ncomb(s, k).tobytes().decode('utf-32-le')
        l.extend([r[i : i + k] for i in range(0, len(r), k)])
    return l

def test():
    ntests = 5
    ftest = lambda: comb('abcdefghij', 1, 6)
    cnt = len(ftest())
    print('Cnt:', cnt)
    timeit_time = timeit.timeit(ftest, number = ntests) / ntests
    print('Total time', round(timeit_time, 3), 'sec,', round(timeit_time / cnt * 10 ** 6, 2), 'mcs per string')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Выход:

```
Cnt: 1111110
Total time 0.548 sec, 0.49 mcs per string
```